# How to automagically generate JSON serialisers and deserialisers for structs/classes at runtime in D?

Tags: json, serialization, d

I'm still new to D, but an obvious missing feature (for web developers) in

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_json.html

is a mixin which creates JSON serialisers and deserialisers for arbitrary (nests) of structs and classes.

i.e.

```
struct Dog {
  string name;
  int age;
}

struct Person {
  mixin JSON;
  string name;
  int age;
  string[] favouriteFoods;
  Dog dog;
  bool retired () { return age > 65 };
}
```

then be able to

```
auto p = Person("\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":45,\"favouriteFoods\":[\"cheese\",\"bananas\"],\"dog\":{\"name\":\"Rover\",\"age\":7}");

p.dog.name -> "rover"
p.favouriteFoods[1] -> "bananas"
p.retired() -> false
```

and

```
p.toJSON(); -> "\"name\":\"Fred\",\"age\":45,\"favouriteFoods\":[\"cheese\",\"bananas\"],\"dog\":{\"name\":\"Rover\",\"age\":7}"
```

Would this be possible using the various meta programming features of D?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: I believe I answered this question by answering your last question... :P

Comment: Pro-tip: There are a number of ways of delimiting string literals in D which can help prevent the backslash-soup above. Try using backticks (`) or the q"<...>" syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible (I have a library which does exactly this in production right now), and D makes it pretty easy to implement using compile-time reflection. You'll want to read up at these links:

- [Traits (compile feature)](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/traits.html)
- [std.traits (library)](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html)
- [Template Mixins](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/template-mixin.html)
- [String Mixins](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/mixin.html)

Comment: What version of D do you use in production now ?

Comment: We generally track with the latest public release (usually waiting a week or two for the dust to settle). So, at the moment, DMD 2.059.